# How to create a sequence for integers in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to create a sequence for a product id to start at 100 in Supabase SQL editor and I'm getting this error:

> Failed to validate SQL query: syntax error at or near ")"

What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
create sequence product_id_seq
    start with 100
    increment by 1
    no maxvalue
    no minvalue;

create table products 
(
    id int4 not null default nextval('product_id_seq'),
    name text not null,
    price numeric(10,2) not null,
    description text,
    category_id integer references categories (id),
    preview text,
    images text[],
    stock integer not null,
    sale boolean,
    sale_price numeric(10,2),
    sale_text text,
    featured integer references featured (id),
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: The code is correct for PostgreSQL. Don't know what this Supabase thing is doing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I found the error, see my answer. Thanks anyways

Comment: Hi, stupid question maybe, but where do you see that sequence created in the supabase editor later? thnx

Comment: @glatocha The only way you can see it in the dashboard is on the field/column you put in when you edit a table, but I believe you run a SQL snippet in the editor to view it but I've never tried before so can't provide the snippet

Answer (score 0):

The error was here:

```
featured integer references featured (id),
```

Apparently the column name can't be the same the table name referenced to, I changed it to:

```
featured_in integer references featured (id),
```

But this is most likely a Supabase thing and not PostgreSQL overall.

Comment: That must be a Supabase problem/bug. Because Postgres does not have such a limitation https://dbfiddle.uk/0VaLxzfK

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Don't think it's a bug but it's like they use a different/limited version of PostgreSQL. For example WITH CHECK OPTION is not supported in Supabase.

Comment: Then you shouldn't tag your question with PostgreSQL if it's not really PostgreSQL